# JBoss logging (log4j) header prints on every line of wrapped entry

Tags: design-patterns, logging, jboss, log4j

Previously in our development evironment, our JBoss logging would only print the log4j header info on the first line of a log entry, where that entry is a string of text wrapped onto many lines (for instance, printing a long SQL statement).

At some point in the last 6 months, this changed and now prints that info on every single line, which makes reading the actual log into a nightmare, and stops us from being able to copy/paste from the log, due to all of the header text.   Note that this does not happen on every line for other (system generated) things that may span multiple lines.

For instance, this is what our logs currently look like for an INFO event:

```
14:36:14,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeplo
ymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean name
d ConfigurationEJB in deployment unit subdeployment "JassEJB3.jar" of deployment
 "jassejb.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/jassejb/JassEJB3/ConfigurationEJB!jass.response.ejb3.active.
ConfigurationLocal
        java:app/JassEJB3/ConfigurationEJB!jass.response.ejb3.active.Configurati
onLocal
        java:module/ConfigurationEJB!jass.response.ejb3.active.ConfigurationLoca
l
        java:global/jassejb/JassEJB3/ConfigurationEJB!jass.response.ejb3.active.
ConfigurationRemote
        java:app/JassEJB3/ConfigurationEJB!jass.response.ejb3.active.Configurati
onRemote
        java:module/ConfigurationEJB!jass.response.ejb3.active.ConfigurationRemo
te
        java:jboss/exported/jassejb/JassEJB3/ConfigurationEJB!jass.response.ejb3
.active.ConfigurationRemote
```

This (above) is how we would like it to look for logs that we send via code (i.e. printing stack traces, SQL statements, etc).    For comparison, this is what a stack trace looks like sent to the logs:

```
14:36:57,142 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 2520) -------- BEGIN OF STACK TRACE -
-------- 
14:36:57,142 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2520) java.sql.SQLRecoverableExceptio
n: Closed Connection
14:36:57,143 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2520)        at oracle.jdbc.driver.Ph
ysicalConnection.prepareCall(PhysicalConnection.java:3416)
14:36:57,144 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2520)        at org.jboss.jca.adapter
s.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareCall(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.j
ava:740)
14:36:57,144 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2520)        at org.jboss.jca.adapter
s.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareCall(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.jav
a:726)
14:36:57,144 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2520)        at org.jboss.jca.adapter
s.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareCall(WrappedConnection.java:597)
```

Does anyone know how we can suppress the logger from inserting "14:36:57,144 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2520" on every line?   It looks like it is doing this because each line is being sent separately.  I have a feeling that SyslogAppender is somehow causing this to happen (splitting up the String), but I'm lost on how to remedy this situation.

Could anyone provide any insight??  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how we can suppress the logger from inserting "14:36:57,144 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 2520" on every line?

In **jboss-logj.xml** file you can configure the format of each log line. 
You will find something like (it may vary from one JBoss version to another):

```xml
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>

    <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
      -->
</layout>
```

The ConversionPattern attribute determines the format of each line. You can add/remove information according to your needs, using different
[characters conversion](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the stack trace was sent to stderr. As far as I know, in JBoss the stdout/stderr interceptors have always converted each line to a log entry.

The solution would be to make sure the string is sent via the logging system, not System.out or System.err.

For instance, instead of:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Use this:

```
log.error("Unexpected exception", e);
```